# iOS Store Kit re-perchase

Tags: ios, storekit

I use Store Kit with a test itunesconnect user account and it works well. Now, I want to reuse this test account or any other test account to repurchase the same product. But, the app doesn't allow resetting purchase status. It tells that I have already purchased this product and noway to sign-out or whatever to do so that re-purchasing for testing purposes.
What should I do to test my product purchase again?

Comment: This is definitely a useless comment!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to test repurchasing features. iTunes automatically handles this based on the type of IAP that you have(subscription/non-subscription). However you may want to adjust your UI to say repurchase rather than buy, by recording it in the NSUserDefaults when you have a successful purchase.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reset the server-side “purchased” state for non-consumables.  You have to create a new test user if you need to test that.

You can reset your client-side “purchased” state, but that's up to you and your implementation.  If you ask StoreKit to purchase an item that's already been purchased, I believe your `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` will receive the same messages as if it were a new purchase, even though the alerts presented to the user will be different.

Comment: how to reset the client-side state? When I try to use another test account, Store-kit uses the first account which has already purchased the item

Comment: How you reset the client-side state is up to you.  What do you do in your app to record that the user has purchased the product?  Do you set a flag in your `NSUserDefaults`?  Do you write a file in your Documents directory?  Whatever you do, you have to undo.

Comment: To try it with a second test account, you need to clear your client-side state (see previous comment), you need to sign out of the first account (in the Settings app, under the Store category), and then you need to launch your app and try to purchase the product.  You will then be able to log in using your second test account.